# How to propagate context via Kleisli?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Just trying to propagate my tracing context inside Kleisli as it was done originally in the [next tutorial](https://medium.com/iadvize-engineering/request-tracing-in-microservices-architecture-a-kleisli-tale-aae8daaa61f).

```
  object TraceLogger {
    def log(msg: String): Kleisli[IO, UUID, Unit] = Kleisli { traceId => IO(println(s"[$traceId] $msg")) }
  }

  trait ServiceStub {
    def request(arg: String): Kleisli[IO, UUID, _]
  }

  trait ClientStub {
    def get(arg: String): Kleisli[IO, UUID, _]
  }

  case class FirstServiceExample(clientStub: ClientStub) extends ServiceStub {
    override def request(arg: String): Kleisli[IO, UUID, _] = Kleisli { (context: UUID) =>
      val requestComputation = clientStub.get("calling second service!")
      TraceLogger.log(arg)
      requestComputation(context)
    }
  }

  case class FirstClientExample(service: FirstServiceExample) {
    def request(): IO[_] = {
      val traceId = UUID.randomUUID()
      service.request("root!").run(traceId)
    }
  }
```

And now I need to run execution:

```
 val exampleClientStub = new ClientStub() {
      override def get(arg: String): Kleisli[IO, UUID, _] = Kleisli.ask
 }

val exampleClientService = FirstServiceExample(exampleClientStub)
FirstClientExample(exampleClientService).request().unsafeRunSync()
```

But, unfortunately, I don't see any logs here. Would you kindly help me to find an issue?

Answer (score 0):

`TraceLogger.log(arg)` This returns an `IO` which is just a description of computation; it is doing nothing.
And since you just leave that value alone it is equivalent to just having a `1` in the middle of your code, it is simply discarded.

You need to chain your `IOs` together to create new `IOs` that represent *"do this and then do that"*, that is basically what the `flatMap` method does.

```scala
Kleisli { (context: UUID) =>
  val requestComputation = clientStub.get("calling second service!")
  TraceLogger.log(arg)(context) >> // >> is equivalent to flatMap(_ => )
  requestComputation(context)
}
```

*(There is probably a better way to write this, I am not used to **Kliesli**)*

---

Fabio's series on *"Programas as Values"* may be very useful: https://systemfw.org/archive.html

Comment: But I have incorrect typing: it's waiting for Kleisli[IO, UUID, NotInfferedB], found IO[_]

Comment: Probably you meant requestComputation(context) >> TraceLogger.log(arg)(context)

Comment: @SlandShow yeah, you are right. I am not used to **Kleisli** it is really clumsy.

Comment: And what do you prefer to use instead?

Comment: @SlandShow usually, just passing the arguments around manually. However, for this case I think that is not a good idea, rather I believe that people use a `Trace[F]` capability trait. I would recommend asking in the **typelevel** **discord** server: https://discord.gg/uTnfsCy4